# Move only 1 cell in table with keyboard-arrow after ajax loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html-table, arrow-keys

Good evening to you all,

I have this problem:
When I'm loading a page (a table-selecter with arrow-keys on keyboard) via ajax,
the active cell is moving 2 cells. I want it to move only 1 cell. If i reload the page (also again with ajax, the active cell moves 3 cells, and so on...
But when i press a button it only moves one cell (which I also want to happen with the arrow-key).

I've created a small example which does generates the same problem. It is written in php so it can fit in one page..
You all can try the php file on your sites, or you can test it here:
http://leslip.be/test/test/test.php

What the php-code does is bassicly creating 2 files which forward to eachothers with the use of ajax.
This is the php-code:

```html
<?php
if (isset($_GET["url"])) $url = $_GET["url"];
    else $url = "home";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .selected { background-color: red; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".to_table").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: "<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
      data: "url=table",
      success: function(response) {
        $("body").html(response);
    }
    });
  });
  $(".to_home").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
        success: function(response) {
          $("body").html(response);
        }
    });
  });
  $(".move").click(function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected').next('td').addClass('selected');
  });
    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        if (key.which == 39) {
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
    if ($url == "home") print "
            <div class=\"site\">
                <div class=\"to_table\">go to table</div>
            </div>
    ";
    elseif ($url == "table") print "
        <div class=\"to_home\">go to home</div>
        <div>
            <table style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">
                <tr>
                    <td class=\"selected\" style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">r</td>
                    <td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">r</td>
                    <td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">r</td>
                    <td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">r</td>
                    <td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">r</td>
                    <td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">r</td>
                    <td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">r</td>
                    <td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">r</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class=\"move\">move selected td</div>
    ";
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code example.

```js
$(function() {
  function getTable() {
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: "/test/test/test.php",
      data: "url=table",
      success: function(response) {
        $("body").html(response);
      }
    });
  }

  function returnHome() {
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: "/test/test/test.php",
      success: function(response) {
        $("body").html(response);
      }
    });
  }

  function prev() {
    if ($('.selected').index() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    $('.selected')
      .removeClass('selected')
      .prev()
      .addClass('selected');
  }

  function next() {
    var c = $("td.selected").siblings().length;
    if ($('.selected').index() >= c) {
      return;
    }
    $('.selected')
      .removeClass('selected')
      .next()
      .addClass('selected');
  }

  function move(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("next")) {
      next();
    } else {
      prev();
    }
  }

  $(".to_table").on('click', getTable);
  $(".to_home").on('click', returnHome);
  $(".move").on('click', move);
  $(document).keydown(function(key) {
    if (key.which == 39) {
      next();
    }
    if (key.which == 37) {
      prev();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}

.button {
  padding: .2em .4em;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="to_home button">go to home</div>
<div>
  <table style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 5px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="selected" style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="move prev button">&lt;</div>
<div class="move next button">&gt;</div>
```

It might better to setup functions since we can then call them from different parts of the UI. It looks like you want either a button click or keystroke to drive the "cursor" in one direction or another. I added `prev` in anticipation of the potential need.

The Move function just helps us more easily assign the event callback. Using `.on()` allows us to bind callback functions to events on elements that are not currently available. Since they will be created from the Ajax calls, this is a better way to manage it.

Now, the the click event and the keystroke event call the same functions that move the cursor. I also added a limiter so the cursor cannot be moved beyond the edge. This is making use of `.index()` to get the index of the current cell in the table between `0` and the number of siblings, in this example `8`.

I hope that helps!

```js
$(function() {
  function getTable() {
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: "/test/test/test.php",
      data: "url=table",
      success: function(response) {
        $("body").html(response);
      }
    });
  }

  function returnHome() {
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: "/test/test/test.php",
      success: function(response) {
        $("body").html(response);
      }
    });
  }

  function prev() {
    if ($('.selected').index() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    $('.selected')
      .removeClass('selected')
      .prev()
      .addClass('selected');
  }

  function next() {
    var c = $("td.selected").siblings().length;
    if ($('.selected').index() >= c) {
      return;
    }
    $('.selected')
      .removeClass('selected')
      .next()
      .addClass('selected');
  }

  function up() {
    var row = $(".selected").parent();
    var cInd = $(".selected").index();
    if (row.index() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    row
      .prev()
      .find("td").eq(cInd)
      .addClass("selected");
  }

  function down() {
    var row = $(".selected").parent();
    var cInd = $(".selected").index();
    if (row.index() >= row.siblings().length) {
      return;
    }
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    row
      .next()
      .find("td").eq(cInd)
      .addClass("selected");
  }

  function wrap(d) {}

  function move(e) {
    var cls = $(e.target).attr("class").split(" ").join("");
    cls = cls.replace("move", "");
    cls = cls.replace("button", "");
    switch (cls) {
      case "next":
        next();
        break;
      case "prev":
        prev();
        break;
      case "up":
        up();
        break;
      case "down":
        down();
        break;
    }
  }

  $(".to_table").on('click', getTable);
  $(".to_home").on('click', returnHome);
  $(".move").on('click', move);
  $(document).keydown(function(key) {
    if (key.which == 39) {
      next();
    }
    if (key.which == 37) {
      prev();
    }
    if (key.which == 38) {
      up();
    }
    if (key.which == 40) {
      down();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}

.button {
  padding: .2em .4em;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="to_home button">go to home</div>
<div>
  <table style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 5px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="selected" style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">r</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="move up button">/\</div>
<div class="move prev button">&lt;</div>
<div class="move next button">&gt;</div>
<div class="move down button">\/</div>
```

Comment: What does the ___go to home___ button do?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix you will have to ask OP. Based on the Test link in the post, I suspect it creates a GET call that collects more HTML and injects it into the page, replacing the current content.

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering if it was broken because it didn't see to work, I just assumed ti should move first box on the left.  But I wasn't sure so thought I should ask...

Comment: this makes me think of my domino on [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151588/draw-me-a-domino/151599#151599) in PHP, I used a matrix of bitwise values.  It was a fun little one.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your answer. Great stuff inside...
But when I use the arrows, the cell moves correctly, but when I reloaded the page (go to home, go to table) and use the arrows on the keyboard, the cell skips again one. Reload the page again, the cell now skips 2, and so on...
It looks like ajax loads the part of moving with the keyboard-arrows multiple times...
But then again, moving with the links, works great. As it did on my (not so nicelly coded) code.

Is there a solution for that problem?

example: http://leslip.be/test/test/test2.php

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. Not the best one. When I open te site, there are no GET-variables in the url. So I used php to check for these, and when there are none, then the jquery "keydown" is written in the html-soure. When there are GET-variables, the jquery code "keydown" is disabled.

```
  <?php if (!isset($_GET["url"])) print "
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    if (key.which == 39) {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
    }
}); "; ?>
```

So this confirmed my what I was thinking, the keydown-function gets loaded more and more when I do a ajax-request.

So still the same question, how can I prevent this on the correct way?